# How to Generate a DSA signature?

Tags: ruby, cocoa

I'm using Sparkle in my Application to do updates but in the documentation it says to generate a DSA Signature and provides a tool to do is (the tool is coded in ruby) but i don't know how to use it. Can someone help?

This is where the documentation is (Step 3): http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/documentation/pmwiki.php/Documentation/BasicSetup?from=Main.HomePage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google'd the command string, and got a handful of hits.

Most useful:

https://answers.launchpad.net/sparkle/+question/50496

Quoting the author:

> It's a script; you need to run it from
>   the command line.
>
> Open the terminal. Change into the
>   Sparkle distribution directory. Type:
>
> ruby "Extras/Signing
>   Tools/generate_keys.rb"
>
> Follow the instructions on the wiki
>   from there.

Answer (score 4):

Also, I'd highly recommend looking at [Feeder](http://reinventedsoftware.com/feeder/) for constructing your Sparkle RSS feed.  It can generate a DSA signature for you automatically, once you drag your binary into an update entry.  It also can upload your binaries and feed to your server for you.  Overall, it's saved me a tremendous amount of time with my Sparkle feeds.

Comment: How do you generate one, when it first asks you, as it says you need to choose one.

Comment: I think you might be confusing the DSA signature for your update with your Sparkle public / private key pair.  Stephen points out how to create that key pair.  You then need to place the public key within your application's bundle.  If you specify the location of your private key within Feeder, it will automatically generate the DSA signature for your updates.

Comment: Where in Feeder do you specify  the location of the Private Key?

Comment: Under version 2.0, if you have created a Sparkle feed, click on that feed.  In the lower-left frame, click on Settings to show the various settings for the feed. The last group of settings should be called Sparkle Appcasting, so click on that.  Within the Sparkle settings, choose 1.5 for the framework version and an option for choosing the private key location should appear at the bottom of the settings screen.  You can also check the "Automatically generate DSA signatures" option from here.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Sparkle Basic wiki page is a bit misleading. For everyone how still gets confused with process, here are necessary steps:

1. go to Extras/Signing Tools subfolder
2. generate dsa private/public key pair:

   ruby generate_keys.rb

   Note that there is bug with this script in Sparkle 1.56b, so it might be better to take it from here: [updated generate_keys.rb script](https://raw.github.com/andymatuschak/Sparkle/55eed9efd84c4a2163a3e2b86c8d9b68a243fb6b/generate_keys.rb)
3. using sign_update.rb script (from same folder) you will generate dsa signature:

   ruby sign_update.rb